# Core Data stack on serial queue results in deadlock

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, deadlock, realm

I'm trying to migrate a core data database to Realm (somewhere between 0-2 million rows), and am running into a deadlock that as far as I can tell, shouldn't be happening.

From a Singleton class, I'm launching the migration like this:

```
_queue = dispatch_queue_create("DiagnosticMigrationQueue", NULL);
    dispatch_async(_queue, ^{
        _realmMigrator = [[CoreDataToRealmMigrator alloc] init];
        [_realmMigrator performMigrationToRealm];
    });
```

Within the `performMigrationToRealm` method, I set up the Core Data stack thusly:

```
- (void) performMigrationToRealm
    {
    self.migrationIsRunning = YES;

    NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSLibraryDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"persistentStore"];

    NSError *error;

    NSManagedObjectModel *model = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSConfinementConcurrencyType];
    context.persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:model];
    [context.persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                 configuration:@"DiagnosticData"
                                                           URL:url
                                                       options:nil
                                                         error:&error];
```

**Understanding Check**: When I create the queue, none of the Core Data stack has been set up yet. Therefore, the NSManagedObjectContext is only created on whatever thread GCD decides to put my block on.

So far, so good. No problems. I now run a method that - in batches of 100,000 - grabs all the NSManagedObjectIds in the Entity. It looks something like this:

```
for (NSInteger numberOfMigratedBatches = 0; numberOfMigratedBatches < totalNumberOfBatches; numberOfMigratedBatches++)
{
    NSArray *samples = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if (samples && !error) 
    {
        [self transferWeightSamplesToRealmWithObjectIds:samples withContext:context];
    }
    [context reset];
    fetchRequest.fetchOffset = batchSize * (numberOfMigratedBatches+1);
}
```

The line that goes funky is the `fetchRequest` in the code block above. Even though I've launched this process on a serial queue, I somehow end up with this:

[image: Three threads stuck on the same line of code]

Each of those minion_duties2 threads is stuck on the same line of code, namely the `fetchRequest` above.

What is going on here? I understand that queues != threads, and that GDC will put my code on whichever thread is sees fit. However, I wouldn't expect that it would put my code on THREE threads. Also, what is com.apple.root.user-initiated-qos.overcommit? I'll say it's overcommitted. I only want this code run one time!

Comment: As far as I can tell, your code looks fine. If I had to guess, I'd say: it's the several different fetchRequests trying to execute on several different threads that could be causing the deadlock. Is there any reason you're doing the batching manually, instead of letting Core Data do it for you by setting the fetchBatchSize property on NSFetchRequest?

Comment: Emm.. probably an oversight on my part. I haven't done a lot of fetchRequests that required batching before, so I didn't realise that Core Data could do it for me.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is technically not an answer to the question you posted, but, it could potentially provide you with a way that would allow you to avoid the problem you're running into (workaround?).

Since my guess is that it's the several different fetch requests trying to execute on several different threads that's causing the deadlock, I would suggest that instead of doing the batching manually, you do it by setting the fetchBatchSize property on NSFetchRequest, and let core data do it for you, and hence avoid doing multiple fetch requests altogether, if memory usage is an issue, try wrapping the innards of your for loop in an autoreleasepool block (I'm guessing there is a for loop inside the `transferWeightSamplesToRealmWithObjectIds:withContext:` method).

Core data has a concept called batching & faulting. From [Apple documentation of NSFetchRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSFetchRequest/fetchBatchSize):

> If you set a non-zero batch size, the collection of objects returned
> when the fetch is executed is broken into batches. When the fetch is
> executed, the entire request is evaluated and the identities of all
> matching objects recorded, but no more than batchSize objects’ data
> will be fetched from the persistent store at a time. The array
> returned from executing the request will be a proxy object that
> transparently faults batches on demand. (In database terms, this is an
> in-memory cursor.)

Hopefully, this helps you somewhat.